# Retrofit2: how to save cookies from response

Tags: android, cookies, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

I need to add some authorization information from cookie in response to next requests.

It works in postman - I make authorization request, then second request, which works fine. But if I delete cookies - second request returns error and I have to do authorization request again.

But in my application this second request always returns the same error. I tried to find needed cookie by using interceptor, but I hadn't found it

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(OAuthInterceptor())

private class OAuthInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()
        com.app.logic.toLog("${chain.proceed(request).header("set-cookie")} ") // it's not that cookie what I looking for
        val headers = chain.proceed(request).headers()
        headers.names().forEach {
            val s = headers.get(it)
            com.app.logic.toLog("$it -> $s")
        }
        return chain + (Session.authConsumer?.let { consumer ->
            consumer.sign(request).unwrap() as Request
        } ?: request)
    }
}
```

Does anybody know what else could I try?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, finally I've found solution for working with cookies

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .cookieJar(UvCookieJar())

private class UvCookieJar : CookieJar {

    private val cookies = mutableListOf<Cookie>()

    override fun saveFromResponse(url: HttpUrl, cookieList: List<Cookie>) {
        cookies.clear()
        cookies.addAll(cookieList)
    }

    override fun loadForRequest(url: HttpUrl): List<Cookie> =
        cookies
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nikhiljha/52d45ca69a8415c6990d2a63f61184ff) on how to intercept cookies when you receive them and send them back in your request in header.

Comment: Thanks, I think it can help. But in this solution I need `Context` and I need to use shared preferences. I've found easier way for solving this

Comment: You can always use application context.

Comment: Yes, I can. But I would prefer to avoid using context and prefs for this. As I said - there is another way without them

Comment: Thank you! It was exactly what I was looking for.